# removing ints from a line

Tags: java, io

So I wrote a program for an finding popular names over different decades and it works, but the outprint gives me a line of the popularity numbers, with each space correlating to a different decade. I want to take these ints and print them individually so I can format this better.

Here is the code:

```
         import java.awt.*;
         import java.io.*;
          import java.util.*;
          import java.io.File;
          import java.awt.*;
          import java.awt.Color;
          import java.awt.Graphics;
           import java.awt.Graphics2D;
          import java. awt.Font;



          public class BabyNames {
              public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
  Scanner inputName = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));

  Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("intoduction");
  System.out.print("Name: ");
  String nameIn = console.next();


  names(inputName, nameIn);
}
public static void names( Scanner inputName, String nameIn)    {
    boolean hasLine = false;
    while(inputName.hasNextLine())  {
        String line = inputName.nextLine();
        Scanner lineScan = new Scanner (line);
        if (lineScan.hasNext()) {
            String name = lineScan.next();
            if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(nameIn))    {
                hasLine = true;
                int year = 1920;

                System.out.print(line);

            }
        }
    }
    if (hasLine == false)   {
        System.out.println("\"" + nameIn + "\" not found.");
    }


    }

    }
```

So an output for a name like Bob would give me
Bob 90 6 450 7
Or something along those lines
I tried using an if `(line.hasNextInt() )`, to print them out individually, but to no avail. is there anyway I can grab these numbers, store them, and then print them in a form like:

> 1950: 90 1960:6 1970: 450 1980:7

Thanks

Comment: Your code makes no sense. Why do you bring in awt (and then why so much **awt**)? Why is an output for a name like Bob "Bob 90 6 450 7"? How is it along those lines? Where did "form like: 1950: 90 1960:6 1970: 450 1980:7" come from? Bob is 1950 6 450 and 7? Why is year always 1920 in the code?

Comment: Because later on in the program I planned on making a DrawingPanel to show a graph of a particular name over the decades. As for Bob, that's just if you type Bob in, Bob would return with those numbers.
that's just the form of the txt file im working with, it has a name, followed by the number for each decade, and then goes to a new line with a new name. Year 1920 was just me experimenting with trying to add in a year with those values.